# SQL - Confusion with INSERT INTO...SELECT and COUNT(*)?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sql-insert

So I have a table `Movement` that has a column called `IDNumber`. What I want to do is count the number of times an ID appears in `IDNumber` for each ID in that column

I could do this individually for each ID like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM movement WHERE IDNumber = 379; 
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM movement WHERE IDNumber = 654;
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM movement WHERE IDNumber = 789;
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM movement WHERE IDNumber = 878;
```

But I want to do this for *all* the the ID's in `IDNumber`, and in one query because the actual dataset that I'm working on is much bigger. So how would I do this?

When I tried to do this, I created another table `IDNumbers` with a columns `ID` that just listed all the distinct ID's present in `Movement`, and I did this:

```
INSERT INTO IDCount(`ID`,`Count`)
SELECT n.ID, m.COUNT(*) 
FROM  movement m  
JOIN IDNumbers n
ON n.ID = m.IDNumber
```

and I want the results to be like:

```
IDNumber   COUNT 
379        2 
654        1 
789        1 
878        1
```

This is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a886/2)** for it.

But I know thats completely wrong... how would I do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: `select idnumber, count(*) .... group by idnumber where idnumber in (379, 654,789,878)`?

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! But I can't just list out all of the ID numbers... in my actual dataset, I have about 9500.

Comment: well, you did say "in one query"... that is the "one query" that accomplishes that... you'd get as many rows back as there are distinct id numbers, e.g. not all 9500, but you'll get multiple rows back.

Comment: @MarcB I meant 9500 distinct ID's actually. Anyway, I found an easier way to do it, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT IDNumber, Count(IDNumber) FROM movement
GROUP BY IDNumber
```

You didn't say it was a requirement that it be inserted into a table, right?

Comment: Thanks! But I would actually want it inserted to a table sorry, because I need to save these results and then add them to another table.

Comment: INSERT INTO IDCount (ID, Count) SELECT IDNumber, Count(IDNumber) FROM Movement GROUP BY IDNumber....by the way, don't name a column COUNT!!

Comment: I'll reiterate in a separate comment.  Don't name a field Count!  Talk about confusing code!  Just for future reference.  Don't want to sound lecturery

Comment: Sorry about that I just realized that. Don't worry, that's not its actual name in the real database :)

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the group by function with MySQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*), IdNumber FROM movement GROUP BY IdNumber;
```

You can even make it fancier by adding more conditions with a where clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*), IdNumber FROM movement WHERE  IDNumber < 1000 GROUP BY IdNumber;
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*), IdNumber FROM movement WHERE  IDNumber IN (1,2,3,4) GROUP BY IdNumber;
```

To save the results into a table -

```
INSERT INTO target_table SELECT COUNT(*), IdNumber FROM movement GROUP BY IdNumber;
```

the target table would have the columns `count`, and `IDNumber`

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT idnumber,COUNT(*) 
    FROM movement 
    group by IDNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the query and the insert:

```
select
    n.id, count(*)
from
    movement m
    join IDNumbers n on m.IDNumber = n.id
group by 
    n.id
;

INSERT INTO IDCount(`ID`,`Count`)
    select
        n.id, count(*)
    from
        movement m
        join IDNumbers n on m.IDNumber = n.id
    group by 
        n.id
;
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a simpler way to do it, but it's helpful to see how it would be done in the method that I was trying to do it in

Comment: Simple is always better, good for you for looking for, finding, and recognizing a better way!